# $\cap_{i=1}^n m_i ^s \subset (\cap_{i=1}^n m_i)^s$ for $m_i$ maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am reading Atiyah & Macdonald Introduction to commutative algebra and in theorem 8.5 in the proof it is said that $\Pi_{i=1}^n m_i ^s \subset (\cap_{i=1}^n m_i)^s$ where $m_i$ are maximal ideal of $R$ an artinian ring . I want to understand why is this true.

What I know is that $\Pi_{i=1}^n m_i ^s \subset (\cap_{i=1}^n m_i^s)$ but then is it true in general that $\cap_{i=1}^n A_i^s \subset (\cap_{i=1}^n A_i)^s$ ? I tried to prove it with no succes. And If this is not true in general how in the case of maximal ideal this is true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Localize at maximal ideals.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just $\prod m_i^s = (\prod m_i)^s \subset (\bigcap m_i)^s$?

Comment: @Mohan what do you mean by localize at maximal ideals.

Comment: If $a\in A$ and $I$ is an ideal $a\in I$ if and only if $a\in I_m$ for every maximal ideal $m$ of $A$.